# rm: cannot remove `dir-name': Directory not empty

Tags: linux, rm

```
ls -al .vscode-server

# . .. bin

ls -al .vscode-server/bin
# . ..
```

I tried to use `rm -rf .vscode-server` to remove .vscode-server, and got `rm: cannot remove 'dir-name': Directory not empty`.

I tried to figure out which process is using dir and found no result.

```
lsof .vscode-server/.
# empty result
```

So, what can I do to remove `.vscode-server`?

Comment: Please ask in SuperUser.  Stack overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

The `rm` command cannot remove non-empty directories unless given the recursive flag `-r`

If you are trying to remove the .vscode-server directory using `rm`, then you would want to use:

```
rm -r .vscode-server
```

Comment: Sorry, I did't describe clearly. I use `rm -rf .vscode-server` and got `rm: cannot remove 'dir-name': Directory not empty`.